# PHPMailer sends email with SMTP authentication but Gmail still claims it cannot validate sender

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer to send SMTP authenticated emails from my PHP scripts. The PHPMailer script works, it throws no errors and I receive my test emails, however they are still flagged as not authenticated in my gmail inbox. (Shown with the little question mark icon).

This is my code:

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require './PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require './PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require './PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';


$mail = new PHPMailer(TRUE);

try {
    $mail->setFrom('noreply@mydomain.com', 'My Domain');
    $mail->addAddress('me@gmail.com', 'Me');
    $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer Test Message';
    $mail->isHTML(TRUE);
    $mail->Body = 'Test email';

    /*SMTP settings*/
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.ionos.co.uk';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Username = 'noreply@mydomain.com';
    $mail->Password = 'myPassword';
    $mail->Port = 587;


    if(!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Message was not sent.';
        echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo 'Message has been sent';
    }

}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->errorMessage();
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Does anyone know why this email is still flagged?
I am using PHPMailer 6.1, the server is running PHP 7.4

Comment: Do you have SPF and DKIM set-up on your domain correctly? (i.e. is `smtp.ionos.co.uk` actually authorized to send mail on behalf of `noreply@mydomain.com`?) Remember that SMTP lets **anyone** send an email **as anyone else**, that's why SPF+DKIM is so important today: not just for spam, but to prevent phishing too.

Comment: Well I was hoping since the email and domain are hosted by the same provider I would be authorised to send emails, but I'll check the SPF+DKIM. Thanks!

Comment: You are authorised to send emails, and therein lies the rub; EVERYONE is authorised to send emails as anyone, and the receiving server tries to validate the identity of the sender using the SPF and DKIM settings. If none are set, anyone can use your emailaddress as the 'FROM' header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So responding to the comments, I solved it by adding an **SPF (TXT) Record** to my domain's DNS. The host field was set to **@** and the weighting to **Hardfail**

Thanks for the help all.

Comment: Curiously with that setup, I can now send emails that are recognised as authenticated, even if edit the 'From:' header to one of my email addresses I have with a different provider. This seems like it's making the authentication a little pointless?

Answer (score 1):

You have to allow gmail to validate your emails with an spf entry in your DNS settings. For more information, please refer to Google docs : https://support.google.com/a/answer/33786